# Render a table from a variable (EJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Im trying to render a table, my variable was extracted from mongodb. This is my attempt in index.ejs

what have I done wrong here?

```
    <table>   
        <tr>
            <th>HomeTeam</th>
        </tr>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= result[i].hteam %> </td>
            </tr>

        <% }); %>
    </table>
```

In the console I get syntax error.

Any help to compile this would be much helpful as it has taken me several weeks to reach this point in my project :)

frederik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unnecessary bracket in closing **for**.

I think it should be:

```
<table>   
    <tr>
        <th>HomeTeam</th>
    </tr>
    <% for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= result[i].hteam %> </td>
        </tr>

    <% }; %>
</table>
```